# How do I to stack arviz.trace_plot() onto an existing matplotlib.plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pymc3, arviz

Basically, I have a few plots for the posteriors and the traces for a pymc3 model. I want to stack it in a stable fashion, with the posterior plot and the traceplot in the same line. Any way to do this?

Comment: You mean stacking plots for different parameters? You can just give multiple parameter names to arviz with the `var_names` argument. Alternatively, `az.plot_trace` does have an undocumented `ax` argument, Which I assume means that you can tell arviz which axis to plot into.

Comment: We need more information to be able to help. What have you tried, what exactly do you want to achieve? https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/api/generated/arviz.plot_trace.html already shows the posterior kde/hist (same plot as plot_posterior) on the left column, only in a different style

Comment: Okay. there is a posterior plot, from the plot_posterior() function, and then there is the traceplot, from the trace_plot() function. i want to line them up horizontally, like the posterior first, then the trace directly to the right of it. the 'ax' thing does not work now. tried it, it says argument not recognized